# Switch from WPS to Express Checkout?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, express-checkout

I currently have a Website Payments Standard checkout process for purchasing annual subscriptions & standalone virtual products, which in its simplest form;

- Collects a few basic details about the customer & logs a new purchase in a database on my site
- Uses the trick of preparing a webform that auto-submits to PayPal on the client-side, using the `custom` field to track & verify the purchase with IPN

As I understand, with Express I could

- Cut out the form technique & tighten my application, initiating the request server-side & then send the user straight to PayPal
- Process the payment instantly when the customer is returned (no waiting on possible IPN delays - though I know I can counter for this with auto-return PDT)
- Manage subscriptions on-site (not required, but acknowledged as a benefit)

However, I am aware of the additional work involved, particularly with recurring payments.

**Would you argue it's worth it for the gains?** Or is what I'm doing acceptable*, given the requirements?

---

*I've always been concerned about exposing the transaction in a standard PayPal webform, which is why I like the idea of Express, but I'm rigorously validating IPN calls; do I have any genuine reason to worry?

Comment: When you say *exposing the transaction in a standard PayPal webform*, do you mean when you are auto-submitting the webform with transaction details on your site that submits to PayPal?

Comment: Well, if anyone were so inclined, they could easily view source and see what's getting POST'ed to PayPal, such as my tracking ID, merchant account, IPN url etc. - I'm aware of self-encrypted buttons, but I'm trying to avoid having to install certificates (shared hosting environment).

Comment: Understandable. Just confirming I was thinking of the same step you were describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Definitely, go for it.
Perhaps I'm biased, but I love Express Checkout as opposed to Website Payments Standard.
In addition to being able to control the recurring payment profiles via ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus, you can also control the LANDINGPAGE for the Express Checkout PayPal landing page ('Billing' or 'Login').

You can use the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile and/or DoExpressCheckoutPayment API response (in case you charge an initial amount) to check for the PAYMENTSTATUS.

Plus, if you ever want to upgrade to Website Payments Pro Direct Recurring Payments (setting up a recurring payment via your own site's credit card form, without leaving to go to the PayPal website), you can simply add in the required additional parameters to the same CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API response.

Lastly, if you ever decide to start using PayPal Digital Goods for Express Checkout including Recurring Payments, all it takes is a few parameter changes in SetExpressCheckout, and for you to load the dg.js file.

The only downside of using Express Checkout Recurring Payments is that there is no equivalent for Enhanced Recurring Payments / Premium Services (allowing you to accept guest-based recurring payments in the US, UK, CA and AU). The only alternative for this would be Website Payments Pro Direct Recurring Payments, which is a slight step up in terms of product offering.

Comment: And perhaps most importantly: it 'feels right'. I've got something against using a clunky form for my payment processing.